# Three planes go thru a point (linear systems)

Tags: linear-algebra

If one was asked to figure out the equations of 3 planes that intersect at
a unique point, how could one figure this out without resorting to trial and error.
Say we want the intersection point to be (1,-3,5).

I really don't see how to do this without some trial and error.
Hope someone can shed some ideas on this.

Comment: The three coordinate planes intersect at the origin. Could you move the whole construction to the point of interest?

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your reply. If one can first get three planes intersecting at the origin, then to move it, would one need to do a translation/transformation of each plane by the point coordinate value of (1,-3,5) ?

Comment: Would that be a correct approach?

Comment: I should note that there are infinitely many possible choices of three planes that intersect at a given point. So what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Just try to figure out what the equation would be if you move, say, $xy$-plane up with one unit.

Comment: HI, this taking xy plane and translating it up one unit, i assume 1 unit on the z-axis, this is something i have tried before. I have to think about it.

Comment: Hi again, if we want to move the xy-plane up one unit on the z-axis, that is make a plane parallel to the original xy-place the equation would be z =1.

Comment: Right, so the moved plane $z=1$ has all points $(*,*,1)$. Now how to move it to get the plane of points $(*,*,5)$ (your last coordinate)? Then experiment with the other two coordinate planes and repeat the argument to get the planes of points $(*, -3,*)$ and $(1,*,*)$.

Comment: So, based on what you are saying, we translate the standard orthogonal planes like xy, yz and xz planes. Won't these planes, be like only one letter. I need to follow up and intersect these to prove they intersect at that point.

Comment: The yz plane has equation x=0, and xz plane has equation y = 0. So if do these movements, i get these equations that are too simplistic to solve via systems of equations solving, i would get z =5, y =-3 and x =1. I guess that makes these planes orthogonal, because we are moving the original standard planes that makes R3 cartesian plane. But this feels like its the trivial solution.

Comment: Note, that the standard planes, are considered to be the trivial planes, we need to find NON-Trivial planes.

Comment: Hi Don Thousand, yes you are exactly correct, there are infinite answers to this, meaning infinite set of 3 planes that would intersect at one point, that being in this case (1,-3,5), i just need to find one set of 3 planes that are not considered trivial planes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of a plane passing through a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is
$$ a(x-x_0) + b (y-y_0) + c(z-z_0) = 0.$$
Different values of the coefficients $a$, $b$, and $c$ give different planes. Pick any three sets of coefficients where the values are not proportional to each other (as they would represent the same plane) and you're done.